# Toggle the segment using a value from formControl

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, form-control

I have a edit page where I am fetching the values from the database. I am trying to assign the value to *ion-segment* automatically.

There is my html with **formControl** and method that's fetches the data from DB:

```js
     this.form = new FormGroup({
                  title: new FormControl(this.task.title,{
                    updateOn: 'blur',
                    validators: [Validators.required]
                  }),
                  description: new FormControl(this.task.description, {
                    updateOn: 'blur',
                    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(180)]
                  }),
                  completed: new FormControl(this.task.completed, {
                    validators: [Validators.required]
                  })
                });
```

```html
      <ion-list-header>Completed</ion-list-header>
            <ion-segment formControlName="completed" value="completed">
              <ion-segment-button  value="true">
                <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
              </ion-segment-button>
              <ion-segment-button value="false">
                <ion-label>No</ion-label>
              </ion-segment-button>
            </ion-segment>
```

I managed to transmit the title and description, but the ion-segment is not assigned. Any advice how I can do it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the *value* attribute on your ion-segment-button is the string "true" instead of the true value. To achieve what you are looking for you need something like this:

```
      <ion-list-header>Completed</ion-list-header>
        <ion-segment [value]="form.value.completed? 'yes' : 'no'">
          <ion-segment-button  value="yes">
            <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
          </ion-segment-button>
          <ion-segment-button value="no">
            <ion-label>No</ion-label>
          </ion-segment-button>
        </ion-segment>
```

Check out [this stackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-bdxfni?file=src/app/app.component.ts).